# В чём отличие между двумя методами отрисовки изображения?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Вопрос по canvas
В чём разница между этими методами отрисовки изображения:

```
    ctx   = example.getContext('2d');
    images  = new Image();
    images.src    = 'img.png';
    ctx.drawImage(images, 0, 0);
```

И вот этим

```
 var img = newImageObject ({
 file : 'img.png',
 countX : 0,
 countY : 0,
 })
```

Может быть я что-то не понял. Что лучше использовать?

Comment: А откуда `newImageObject` (или `new ImageObject`)? Бегло не гуглится

Comment: newImageObject это функция из библиотеки PointJS. В этом и отличие.

Comment: Второй способ просто удобней и является оберткой для первого